# create a rule in R to count number of consultations per patient per day

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, rules, cycle

I have created the following dataset with key scenarios that I have in my actual dataset:

```
df <- data.frame (organisation_id  = c("1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
                  patient_id = c("1230","1230","1222","1222","1244","1244","987","987","2223","2223","2247","2247","2247","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1239","1239","1239","3322","3322","3322","5434","5434","4488","4488","4488","1250","1250"),
                  date = c("08-02-2018","08-02-2018","12-01-2018","12-01-2018","12-01-2018","22-02-2018","12-01-2018","22-02-2018","01-03-2019","01-03-2019","01-03-2019","01-03-2019","01-03-2019","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","12-07-2020","13-07-2020","13-07-2020","13-07-2020","16-06-2021","16-06-2021","16-06-2021","14-05-2019","14-05-2019","17-03-2020","17-03-2020","17-03-2020","03-02-2019","03-02-2019"),
                  consultation_mode = c("Telephone","Face-to-Face","Telephone","Telephone","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Telephone","Telephone","Home visit","Home visit","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Telephone","Telephone","Telephone","Telephone","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Home visit","Home visit","Home visit","Face-to-Face","Telephone","Face-to-Face","Telephone","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face","Telephone","Telephone","Face-to-Face","Face-to-Face"),
                  professional_id = c("24","11","123","110","123","110","123","333","444","444","444","444","444","1133","12","25","26","12","34","35","38","44","44","5556","443","443","445","29","29","555","5556","12","1133","113663"),
                  professional_role = c("Doctor","Support","Doctor","Support","Doctor","Support","Doctor","Nurse","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Support","Support","Nurse","Nurse","Support","Doctor","Doctor","Nurse","Nurse","Nurse","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Doctor","Support","Support","Support"),
                  professional_name = c("Dr John Taylor","Mary Wright","Dr Patricia Jones","James Davies","Dr Patricia Jones","James Davies","Dr Patricia Jones","Peter Hall","Dr Mary Wilson","Dr Mary Wilson","Dr Mary Wilson","Dr Mary Wilson","Dr Mary Wilson","Mary Wright","Anthony Patel","Jennifer Walker","Jennifer Walker","Anthony Patel","Dr Carol Bell","Dr Carol Bell","Deborah Dixon","Kevin R Collins","Kevin Collins","Dr Robert Brown","Dr Mary Wilson","Dr Mary Wilson","Dr John Snow","Dr John Taylor","Dr John Taylor","Dr James Smith","Dr Robert Brown","Anthony Patel","Mary Wright","Mary TEST Wright")
)

df$organisation_id <- as.factor(df$organisation_id)
df$patient_id <- as.factor(df$patient_id)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
df$consultation_mode <- as.factor(df$consultation_mode)
df$professional_id <- as.factor(df$professional_id)
df$professional_role <- as.factor(df$professional_role)
```

I want to create two extra columns (`include?` and `Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day`) as per the below:

For each `organisation_id`, `patient_id`, `date` and `consultation_mode` check:

**1-** If there is only 1 row, `include?` = 1 and `Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day` = 1 for that `professional_role`.

**2-** If there is more than 1 row, `include?` = 1 for each different `professional_id` and `professional_name` with `consultation_role` = 'Doctor' or 'Nurse'.

**Note:** if there are 2+ entries for ‘Doctor’ or ‘Nurse’ with different `professional_id` but same `professional_name`, the first row gets `include?` = 1 and the following rows `include?` = 0. E.g. 25 / 26 IDs for Jennifer Walker. Similarly, if there are 2+ entries for ‘Doctor’ or ‘Nurse’ with same `professional_id` but different `professional_name`, the first row gets `include?` = 1 and the following rows `include?` = 0. E.g. 44 ID for Kevin R Collins / Kevin Collins.

**2.1-** If there is 0 'Doctor' or 'Nurse' (all ‘Support’), then the first row gets `include?` = 1 and the following rows `include?` = 0, with `Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day` = 1 for that `professional_role`.

**Intermediate dataset:**

| organisation_id | patient_id | date | consultation_mode | professional_id | professional_role | professional_name | include? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Telephone | 24 | Doctor | Dr John Taylor | 1 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Face-to-Face | 11 | Support | Mary Wright | 1 |
| 2 | 1222 | 12-01-2018 | Telephone | 123 | Doctor | Dr Patricia Jones | 1 |
| 2 | 1222 | 12-01-2018 | Telephone | 110 | Support | James Davies | 0 |
| 2 | 1244 | 12-01-2018 | Face-to-Face | 123 | Doctor | Dr Patricia Jones | 1 |
| 2 | 1244 | 22-02-2018 | Face-to-Face | 110 | Support | James Davies | 1 |
| 2 | 987 | 12-01-2018 | Telephone | 123 | Doctor | Dr Patricia Jones | 1 |
| 2 | 987 | 22-02-2018 | Telephone | 333 | Nurse | Peter Hall | 1 |
| 3 | 2223 | 01-03-2019 | Home visit | 444 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 1 |
| 3 | 2223 | 01-03-2019 | Home visit | 444 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 0 |
| 3 | 2247 | 01-03-2019 | Face-to-Face | 444 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 1 |
| 3 | 2247 | 01-03-2019 | Face-to-Face | 444 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 0 |
| 3 | 2247 | 01-03-2019 | Face-to-Face | 444 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Telephone | 1133 | Support | Mary Wright | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Telephone | 12 | Support | Anthony Patel | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Telephone | 25 | Nurse | Jennifer Walker | 1 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Telephone | 26 | Nurse | Jennifer Walker | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Face-to-Face | 12 | Support | Anthony Patel | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Face-to-Face | 34 | Doctor | Dr Carol Bell | 1 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Face-to-Face | 35 | Doctor | Dr Carol Bell | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 12-07-2020 | Face-to-Face | 38 | Nurse | Deborah Dixon | 1 |
| 4 | 1239 | 13-07-2020 | Home visit | 44 | Nurse | Kevin R Collins | 1 |
| 4 | 1239 | 13-07-2020 | Home visit | 44 | Nurse | Kevin Collins | 0 |
| 4 | 1239 | 13-07-2020 | Home visit | 5556 | Doctor | Dr Robert Brown | 1 |
| 4 | 3322 | 16-06-2021 | Face-to-Face | 443 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 1 |
| 4 | 3322 | 16-06-2021 | Telephone | 443 | Doctor | Dr Mary Wilson | 1 |
| 4 | 3322 | 16-06-2021 | Face-to-Face | 445 | Doctor | Dr John Snow | 1 |
| 4 | 5434 | 14-05-2019 | Telephone | 29 | Doctor | Dr John Taylor | 1 |
| 4 | 5434 | 14-05-2019 | Face-to-Face | 29 | Doctor | Dr John Taylor | 1 |
| 4 | 4488 | 17-03-2020 | Face-to-Face | 555 | Doctor | Dr James Smith | 1 |
| 4 | 4488 | 17-03-2020 | Telephone | 5556 | Doctor | Dr Robert Brown | 1 |
| 4 | 4488 | 17-03-2020 | Telephone | 12 | Support | Anthony Patel | 0 |
| 4 | 1250 | 03-02-2019 | Face-to-Face | 1133 | Support | Mary Wright | 1 |
| 4 | 1250 | 03-02-2019 | Face-to-Face | 113663 | Support | Mary TEST Wright | 0 |

**Final dataset:**
Example for one `organisation_id`,`patient_id`,`date` and for each category of `consultation_mode` and `professional_role`.

| organisation_id | patient_id | date | consultation_mode | professional_role | Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Face-to-Face | Doctor | 0 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Face-to-Face | Nurse | 0 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Face-to-Face | Support | 1 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Telephone | Doctor | 1 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Telephone | Nurse | 0 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Telephone | Support | 0 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Home visit | Doctor | 0 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Home visit | Nurse | 0 |
| 1 | 1230 | 08-02-2018 | Home visit | Support | 0 |

etc.

Any ideas on how to do this in R in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, for each row we want to evaluate the following conditions to decide whether `include? = 1`:

1. The row's group size for organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode is 1
2. The row's group size for organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode is greater than 1 AND the row corresponds to a:

   1. Doctor AND is the *first* among doctors with the same id/name
   2. Nurse AND is the *first* among nurses with the same id/name
   3. Support AND is the *first* among support AND is part of a organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode group that has no doctor or nurse

This logic will create the "intermediate" table. To create the "final" table, we go through each category of consultation_mode and professional_role and set `Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day = 1` if there's a corresponding entry with `include? = 1`.

Based on the above expectation, here's how I'd do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

# For each row, add the size of its 
# organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode group
df2 <- df %>% group_by(organisation_id, patient_id, date, consultation_mode) %>% 
    mutate(group_size = n()) %>% ungroup()

# For each row, indicate whether it's the first entry of 
# organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode-professional_role group 
# of people with the SAME NAME but possiblly different ID
df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(organisation_id, patient_id, date, consultation_mode, 
        professional_role, professional_name) %>% 
    mutate(first_by_name = row_number()==1) %>% 
    ungroup()

# For each row, indicate whether it's the first entry of 
# organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode-professional_role group 
# of people with the SAME ID but possiblly different name
df4 <- df3 %>% group_by(organisation_id, patient_id, date, consultation_mode, 
        professional_role, professional_id) %>% 
    mutate(first_by_id = row_number()==1) %>% 
    ungroup()

# For each row, indicate whether there's no doctor/nurse in its 
# organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode
# and indicate the first entry in such support-only group
df5 <- df4 %>% group_by(organisation_id, patient_id, date, consultation_mode) %>% 
    mutate(support_only_group = length(intersect(professional_role, c("Doctor", "Nurse"))) == 0) %>% 
    mutate(first_in_support_only = row_number()==1 & support_only_group) %>% 
    ungroup()

# Apply rules to determine the inclusion status of each row
df6 <- df5 %>% mutate(`include?` = if_else(
        group_size == 1 | 
        (professional_role %in% c("Doctor","Nurse") & (first_by_name & first_by_id)) |
        first_in_support_only, 1, 0)) 
df6
```

[image]

Convert into the final table:

```
# Convert into the final table
df7 <- df6 %>% 
    select(-c(group_size, first_by_name, first_by_id, support_only_group, first_in_support_only)) %>% 
    group_by(organisation_id, patient_id, date) %>% 
    expand(consultation_mode, professional_role) %>%
    left_join(df6) %>%
    mutate(Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day = replace_na(`include?`,0)) %>%
    select(-c(professional_id, professional_name, `include?`)) %>%
    group_by(organisation_id, patient_id, date, consultation_mode, professional_role) %>%
    summarise(Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day = sum(Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day))

df7 %>% filter(patient_id %in% c(2223, 1250, 1230))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin, this is a great approach. 2 points I wanted to raise:
1-For multiple entries of 'Support', it does not matter if they have professional_id/name different, it should only count as 1 and at the moment it counts 2. I have changed the last row of the df to highlight this.
2-Lines 58-61 of final df, for patient_id 2223, ideally it should be 3 entries for each consultatoin_mode, so only 1 'Doctor' and the total 1+0 in this case 1. How would you account for these 2 points in your routine?

Comment: Thanks @DanielaRodrigues for the test cases! To account for the first point, I've added a `first_in_support_only` check. To account for the second point, I've performed a summation of `Nr_consultations_per_Pt_day` by `organisation_id-patient_id-date-consultation_mode-professional_mode` group as the final operation. The answer has been revised with these changes.